# How to install and use arara package?

Tags: texlive, windows, arara

I am interested in using "arara" package.
According to it's manual my below code should run without any error:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello world.
\end{document}
```

but I get nothing and have problem with this code.
It should be mentioned that I install Java after installing LaTeX.
Error:

> Process started: "C:/texlive/2015/bin/win32/arara.exe"
>
> C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:680:
>   C:\texlive\2015\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: program not found (not
>   part of TeX Live): java.exe
>
> Process exited with error(s)

Comment: but can java be found on the commandline? Try running `java` in a dos prompt

Comment: Yes
than you for your attention.\\ I installed JRE now i'm going to install JDK.

Comment: Yes it works...

Comment: and does arara work from the command line using your MWE?

Comment: You don't need the JDK just to run `arara`. The JRE should be sufficient. (JDK is for compiling the Java code. The JRE is just for running pre-compiled Java code.) What do you get if you do `java -version` in the dos prompt?

Comment: I give this:

java version "1.8.0_102"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.102-b14, mixed mode).

Comment: But after installing JDK it run beautiful! Now I have a different problem, It works but no PDF file generated

Comment: someone should post an answer to this, perhaps with a link to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Answer (score 2):

> I am composing this answer after gathering the comments of [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif), [hossein-behboodi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/70403/hossein-behboodi), [nicola-talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot), [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes)

Basically, if `arara` fails to work, one must check if we can run `Java` from the command line (DOS prompt for Windows).

```
java -version
```

If it fails install Java. Things will start working. If not, see [How to get arara working with TeXstudio](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1862).

[nicola-talbot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) says
Only JRE is required. JDK is for compiling the Java code. The JRE is just for running pre-compiled Java code.

[cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/6621/cmhughes)  says it would be nice to see [java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/java-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: I see my username in the answer, but I'm not sure why...? Could you let me know?

Comment: I was giving credit to you @cmhughes as I had used your comment "someone should post an answer to this, perhaps with a link to stackoverflow.com/questions/15796855/… – cmhughes Aug 10 '16 at 10:30"  in the answer

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! I hadn't looked through the original comments, my apologies. Thanks for putting an answer together :)